# How to write a function that copies all of the elements of a list except the largest value into another list? Python 3.2

Tags: python, list, function, copy

I'm trying to answer this question on a practice test:

Write a function, def eliminate(x, y), that copies all the elements of the list x except the largest value into the list y.

The best thing I could come up with is:

```
def eliminate(x, y):
    print(x)
    y = x
    big = max(y)
    y.remove(big)
    print(y)
def main():
    x = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
    y = [0]
    eliminate(x, y)
main()
```

I don't think that'll cut it if a question like that comes up on my final, and I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be writing a main function with it, just the eliminate one.  So how would I answer this?  (keep in mind this is an introductory course, I shouldn't be using more advanced coding)

Comment: Your function works so unless you've been told to approach this in a different way it should be an acceptable answer. If the test were to ask you just to define the function then just define the function don't worry about a main function or an example implementation unless it specifies that is required (in which case I think it would be fine to have a main function). Also, your list y should be a blank list (instead of containing 0) just use; y = []

Comment: I suggest reading "How to think like a computer scientist". There are several editions for python. including this interactive one http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do this:

```
def eliminate(x, y):
    largest = max(x)
    y[:] = [elem for elem in x if elem != largest]
```

This fills `y` with all the elements in `x` except whichever is largest.  For example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = []
>>> eliminate(x, y)
>>> y
[1, 2]
>>> x = [7,10,10,3,4]
>>> eliminate(x, y)
>>> y
[7, 3, 4]
```

This assumes that by "copies" the question is asking for the contents of `y` to be replaced.  If the non-maximal elements of `x` are to be appended to `y`, you could use `y.extend` instead.

Note that your version doesn't handle the case where there are multiple elements with the maximum value (e.g. `[1,2,2]`) -- `.remove()` only removes one of the arguments, not all of them.

Comment: I just have a question: what is elem?

Comment: @user1751335: that structure is known as a list comprehension.  `elem` is just the name I gave to each element in `x`.  `newlist = [a*2 for a in seq]` is basically the same as `newlist = []; for a in seq: newlist.append(a*2)`.  I strongly recommend reading through the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the largest number in a list you will need to iterate over that list and keep trace of the largest element along the way. There are several ways to achieve this.

So this code answers the question:

```
y.extend([n for n in x if n != max(x)])
```

but i'm worried it might not solve your problem, which is learning how and why this works. Here is that code expanded into a very straight forward way that just uses for loops and if statments.

```
def trasfer_all_but_largest(transfer_from_list, transfer_to_list):

    current_index = 0
    index_of_current_largest_element = 0
    largest_element_so_far = None

    for element in transfer_from_list:
        if current_index == 0:
            largest_element_so_far = element
        else:
            if element > largest_element_so_far:
                largest_element_so_far = element
                index_of_current_largest_element = current_index
        current_index = current_index + 1

    index_of_largest_element = index_of_current_largest_element

    current_index = 0 # reset our index counter

    for element in transfer_from_list:
        if current_index == index_of_largest_element:
            continue # continue means keep going through the list
        else:
            transfer_to_list = transfer_to_list + [element]

        current_index = current_index + 1

    return transfer_to_list

list_with_large_number = [1, 2, 100000]
list_were_transfering_to = [40, 50]

answer_list = trasfer_all_but_largest(list_with_large_number, list_were_transfering_to)
print(answer_list)
```

Comment: I don't know what that means.  I missed a lot of class and I'm basically teaching myself the course through the textbook, but it doesn't mention this in there.